# Retrieve a category and its associated products based on a condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I have a MVC application that I'm creating based on MVC Music Store tutorial and instead of a Music Store, I'm building a fashion & clothing store. I have changed the partial views to display the Brands (Artists on the MusicStore) and Categories (Genres) and the products would have to be filtered by gender. I have tried different approaches but nothing comes close to my expectations.

Here's a sample from `StoreController`:

```
    public ActionResult Brand(int cod)
    {
        // Retrieve Brand and its associated Products from database
        var brandModel = storeDB.Brands.Include("Products")
            .Single(g => g.BrandId == cod);

        return View(brandModel);
    }
```

I am trying to get something like this:

> /Store/Browse/Man?Type=1
>   /Store/Browse/Woman?Type=1
>   /Store/Browse/Man?Brand=1
>   /Store/Browse/Woman?Brand=1

The menu would be...

- Woman

  - Browse by style

    - [CATEGORIES]
  - Browse by brand

    - [BRANDS]
- Man

  - Browse by style

    - [CATEGORIES]
  - Browse by brand

    - [BRANDS]

Brands can have products for both genders, but when browsing from `/Man?Brand=1` it should show only man's clothing and If a brand has only woman's clothing, this brand shouldn't be listed on `Man / Browse by Brand` menu.

What do I have to change on the `ActionResults` to validate the Gender column on Products table?

Comment: This is really a quesion aout the data, not an MVC question.  Are you using Linq or EF?  This will help determine the correct tags for this question.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that I'm using entity framework.

Answer (score 0):

If we use the following simplified models:

```
public class Brand
{
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    public string BrandName { get; set; }
    // other properties
}

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    // other properties
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string ProductGender { get; set; }
    // other properties
}
```

Then we can create our gender-specific categories as follows:

**UPDATED**

```
var womenByStyle = (from p in _db.Products where p.ProductGender == "Female"
    join c in _db.Categories on c.CategoryId equals p.CategoryId
    select c.CategoryId, c.CategoryName).Distinct();

var womenByBrand = (from p in _db.Products where p.ProductGender == "Female"
    join b in _db.Brand on b.BrandId equals p.BrandId
    select b.BrandId, b.BrandName).Distinct();
```

We can do specific searches in our querystring (such as `Man?Brand=1`) as follows:

```
public ActionResult Man(int? Brand, int? Style)
{
    if (Brand != null)
    {
        var brandProductsForMale = from p in _db.Products 
            where p.ProductGender == "Male" && BrandId == Brand;

        // map to ViewModel

        return View("Products", brandProductsForMaleModel);
    }

    // et cetera
}
```

Comment: Tried this and got some errors. Where should I put the vars womenByStyle, womenByBrand, etc? I've put on my StoreController() and got errors on c.CategoryId (the name c is not in scope on the left side of equals), select (expected contextual keywork equals), distinct (does not exist in the current context). On the ActionResult I received an error on "where" (Delegate does not take 1 arguments)...

Comment: Sprite, sorry, if I had run my LINQ statements through LINQPad, I would have seen my errors.  The corrected LINQ statements are above.

Comment: Still got some errors here, "cannot use local variable c before it is declared", "the name p is not in the scope on the right side of equals" and on the select statement, select c.CategoryId, c.CategoryName "; expected"